# iPhone . UIToolbar not working with some buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIToolbar.

If I create a UIBarButton like this, it works:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:iOB style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myStuff)];
[button setTitle:@"Hi"];
```

If I create the UIBarButton like this, cause I want it to be colored:

```
UIImageView *vUP = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:iUP];
UIBarButtonItem *UPButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:vUP];
[UPButton setAction:@selector(anotherStuff)];
[UPButton setTitle:@"Hi";
[UPButton setTarget:self];
[vUP release];
```

The button shows, WITHOUT title and will doesn't respond to any touch...

am I missing something?

Comment: not sure, but don't you think you have to give your custom view (vUP) a frame like UPButton.bounds?

Comment: as far as I know, imageViews create its bounds based on the image it loads on initWithImage, isn't it? and why isn't the title showing? Anyway I have printed vUP bounds to console and it shows (0, 0, 53, 53)

Comment: Why not using a proper UIButton as the custom view for the BarButtonItem?

Comment: @Digital Robot: What does vUP.frame say when logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plain_btn-75-30.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);

UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];   
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPress:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [someButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    someButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];

    [someButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     UPButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
```

If you want image and title both then image must be set as a background image with title.

Comment: Thanks, but there's just one problem, the title is appearing on the middle of the button, over the image. I wonder if there's a way to push it down, without having to add a UILabel.

Comment: Yes DR, title always shown inside the middle of button,over the image. If you need text alignment according to your requirement ,then make a new image with title over their.

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIButton instead of the UIImageView as a UIImageView does not respond to touch events.
You will, under no circumstance get a title as you provided a custom view.